# Trying to search Active Directory using Ambiguous Name Resolution but it never returns anything

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, directoryservices

Unable to get it to return any results. Compiles fine and does not error when it is run, but the results are always empty.

I have got this working if I restrict it to something like DisplayName or given name. But would like it to work no matter if the user puts in forename or surname first and that the user is not restricted to adhering to the DisplayName format of "Surname, Forename"

```
Dim searchterm As String = RouteData.Values("Search")
Dim domain As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Domain")
Dim user As New CustomUserPrincipal(domain)
Dim search As New PrincipalSearcher()
Dim results As PrincipalSearchResult(Of Principal)

jss.MaxJsonLength = Integer.MaxValue
user.Anr = String.Format("*{0}*", searchterm)
search.QueryFilter = user
CType(search.GetUnderlyingSearcher, DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher).SizeLimit = 25
results = search.FindAll()
```

```
<DirectoryObjectClass("user")>
<DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")>
Public Class CustomUserPrincipal
    Inherits UserPrincipal

    Public Sub New(context As PrincipalContext)

        MyBase.New(context)

    End Sub

    <DirectoryProperty("anr")>
    Public Property Anr As String
        Get
            Return CStr(ExtensionGet("anr")(0))
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            ExtensionSet("anr", value)
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

I am expecting an object that I can enumerate through and pull out individual UserPrincipals to extract details. But I only get an empty object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your problem:

```
user.Anr = String.Format("*{0}*", searchterm)
```

Specifically, that you're putting asterisks around your search term. According to the [documentation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx), it will expand a search term like `(anr=Smith)` to something like this:

```
(|(displayName=smith*)(givenName=smith*)(legacyExchangeDN=smith)(physicalDeliveryOfficeName=smith*)(proxyAddresses=smith*)(Name=smith*)(sAMAccountName=smith*)(sn=smith*))
```

Notice that it already does a "starts with" type search. Putting your own wildcards in there messes it up.

More specifically, it's the asterisk at the beginning. I tested this in our own AD environment. If I search for `(anr=*Gabriel*)` or `(anr=*Gabriel)`, I get no results. If I search for `(anr=Gabriel*)` I get results, but it really has no effect on the results (the results are the same as if I had searched for `(anr=Gabriel)`).

The solution is to change that line to this:

```
user.Anr = searchterm
```

It is not exactly equivalent to the "contains" search you seem to want, but putting a wildcard at the beginning of any search really kills performance anyway. It can no longer use any indexes to complete the search, so it's forced to look at *every* user account in your domain.